# Limit to amount of questions asked daily

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Lately, it seems that some users ask countless questions in succession.  Is this something that is encouraged? I believe that if there was a question limit ,users would be forced to think over their questions more carefully ,and investigate whether their question s have been asked before ,or can easily be found on Google. Forgive me if this comes off the wrong way ,that is not intended.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294

Comment: I'm referring to users who do have some ratings ,but I guess there isn't a way to limit someone from asking 50 questions in a row on what bracha to make on different  items or something similar like that ...

Comment: I agree, it can be exhausting. And I think it might (*might*) encourage a little more thought before people ask.